# How can I implement derived-class constructors by reusing base-class constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, multiple-inheritance

Let us look at the following class:

**ProjectManager.hh**

```
#ifndef INPUT_CPP_FILES_PROJECT_MANAGER_HH
#define INPUT_CPP_FILES_PROJECT_MANAGER_HH

#include <string>

#include "Employee.hh"
#include "Programmer.hh"
#include "Tester.hh"

namespace OrganizationNamespace {
    class ProjectManager : public Programmer, public Tester {
    public:
        ProjectManager():Employee(), Programmer(), Tester()
        {}

        explicit ProjectManager(const std::string& id):Employee(id), Programmer(), Tester()
        {}

        ProjectManager(std::string&id, std::string &name):Employee(id, name), Programmer(), Tester()
        {}

        ProjectManager(std::string &id, std::string &name, std::string &programming_language):Employee(id, name), Programmer(programming_language), Tester()
        {}

        ProjectManager(std::string &id, std::string &name, std::string &programming_language, std::string &tool):Programmer(programming_language), Tester(tool),Employee(id, name)
        {}

        ProjectManager(ProjectManager const & pm)
        {
            this->id_ = pm.id_;
            this->name_ = pm.name_;
            this->programming_language_ = pm.programming_language_;
            this->tool_ = pm.tool_;
        }

        void print() const {
            std::cout << "(" << Employee::id_ << ", " << Employee::name_ << ", " << Programmer::programming_language_ << "," << Tester::tool_ << ")"
                      << std::endl;
        }
    };
}
#endif //INPUT_CPP_FILES_PROJECT_MANAGER_HH
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Employee.hh"
#include "Programmer.hh"
#include "ProjectManager.hh"

int main()
{
    std::string id  = "id";
    std::string name  = "name";
    std::string programming_language  = "programming-language";
    std::string testing_tool  = "testing-tool";

    OrganizationNamespace::ProjectManager pm(id, name, programming_language, testing_tool);
    pm.print();
}
```

**Output**

```
C:\Users\pc\source\repos\input_cpp_files\cmake-build-debug\input_cpp_files.exe
(id, name, ,)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As we can see the program is not giving the correct output.

The expected output is:

```
C:\Users\pc\source\repos\input_cpp_files\cmake-build-debug\input_cpp_files.exe
(id, name, programming-language, testing-tool)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I implement constructors in `ProjectManager` so that they give the correct output?

---

---

---

**Additional Source Code**

**Employee.hh**

```
#ifndef INPUT_CPP_FILES_EMPLOYEE_HH
#define INPUT_CPP_FILES_EMPLOYEE_HH

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace OrganizationNamespace {
    class Employee {
    protected:
        std::string id_;
        std::string name_;

    public:
        Employee() : id_ (""), name_("") {}

        Employee(const std::string &id) : id_(id), name_("") {}

        Employee(const std::string &id, const std::string &name) : id_(id), name_(name) {}

        Employee(Employee const & emp)
        {
            this->id_ = emp.id_;
            this->name_ = emp.name_;
        }

        void print() const
        {
            std::cout << "(" << id_ << ", " << name_ << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    };
}
#endif //INPUT_CPP_FILES_EMPLOYEE_HH
```

**Programmer.hh**

```
#ifndef INPUT_CPP_FILES_PROGRAMMER_HH
#define INPUT_CPP_FILES_PROGRAMMER_HH

#include "Employee.hh"

namespace OrganizationNamespace {
    class Programmer : public virtual Employee {
    protected:
        std::string programming_language_;

    public:
        Programmer() : Employee(), programming_language_("") {}

        Programmer(std::string id) : Employee(id) {}

        Programmer(std::string id, std::string name) : Employee(id, name) {}

        Programmer(std::string id, std::string name, std::string programming_language) : Employee(id, name),
                                                                                         programming_language_(
                                                                                                 programming_language) {}

        void print() const {
            std::cout << "(" << id_ << ", " << name_ << ", " << programming_language_ << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    };
}

#endif //INPUT_CPP_FILES_PROGRAMMER_HH
```

**Tester.hh**

```
#ifndef INPUT_CPP_FILES_TESTER_HH
#define INPUT_CPP_FILES_TESTER_HH

#include <string>

#include "Employee.hh"

namespace OrganizationNamespace {

    class Tester : public virtual Employee {
    protected:
        std::string tool_;

    public:
        Tester() : Employee(), tool_("") {}

        Tester(std::string id) : Employee(id) {}

        Tester(std::string id, std::string name) : Employee(id, name) {}

        Tester(std::string id, std::string name, std::string tool) : Employee(id, name), tool_(tool) {}

        void print() const {
            std::cout << "(" << id_ << ", " << name_ << ", " << tool_ << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    };
}
#endif //INPUT_CPP_FILES_TESTER_HH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 4-parameter `ProjectManager` constructor calls the 1-parameter `Programmer` constructor, which does not set the `programming_language_` member. The same for the `Tester` constructor.

So neither of the member variables for your two classes get anything other than default initialized to empty strings.

The solution is to pass the proper values in the proper parameters, and construct the base classes in the correct order.

```
namespace OrganizationNamespace {
    class ProjectManager : public Programmer, public Tester {
    public:
        // ...
        ProjectManager(std::string &id, std::string &name, std::string &programming_language):
            Employee(id, name), Programmer(id, name, programming_language), Tester()
        {}

        ProjectManager(std::string &id, std::string &name, std::string &programming_language, std::string &tool):
            Employee(id, name), Programmer(id, name, programming_language), Tester(id, name, tool)
        {}
        // ...
    };
```

Even though the `id` and `name` parameters won't be used by the `Programmer` or `Tester` constructors (because the `Employee` base class they are passed to is virtual and will be constructed by the most derived object, `ProjectManager`), we still pass in those values. There are a couple of reasons for that.

1. Because we already have these `string` objects, and the constructors take their parameters as references, we avoid the overhead of constructing temporary string objects that will be unused.
2. The code does not rely on the assumption that the `id` and `name` paramaters are unused. It is possible that a future change to the constructors will make use of one or both parameters. By passing in the expected values that can avoid future bugs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you call the `ProjectManger` cosntructor you also call the overloaded cosntructors of `Programmer` and `Tester`, the versions you are calling are those which take as parameter one `std::string`, those constructors change the value of `Employee::id_`, actually you never changed other values.
For fixing the problem you must change

```
ProjectManager(std::string& id, std::string& name, std::string& programming_language, std::string& tool) : 
Employee(id, name), 
Programmer(programming_language), 
Tester(tool) 
{}
```

in

```
ProjectManager(std::string& id, std::string& name, std::string& programming_language, std::string& tool) : 
Employee(id, name), 
Programmer("","",programming_language), 
Tester("","",tool) 
{}
```

Comment: It would be better to pass in the known `id` and `name` values to the `Programmer` and `Tester` classes. This avoids the construction of multiple temporary `std::string` objects and also avoids the assumption that they will be unused within the constructor.

Comment: Yes but this is a virtual inheritence, because of the rules of c++ calling a constructor of a grandson class(ProjectManager) and you didn't specify which granparent class(Employee) constructor the compiler call the default constructor, so you must call the overloaded constructor. But yours is a good point, he could use `const std::string &` instead of  `std::string` , so the program does not need to cretae useless string

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, I would request you to kindly post an answer with your proposed solution.

Comment: @user366312 I've updated my existing answer with the example code and explanation